# Social media link in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, facebook-social-plugins, python-social-auth

I want to set a social link at the end of my post in the Django template.
how to use social media link in Django's post for sharing my posts in the social?

Comment: Use a token for your social share HTML and add that to the context when rendering the page. When writing the method which returns the HTML, keep in mind what you need to use for the social sharing link in order to make it work. Normally you pass the page URL, I believe.

Answer (score 12):

Check out django-social-share (https://github.com/fcurella/django-social-share) or django-socialsharing (https://github.com/lettertwo/django-socialsharing).

More can be found here: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/social/

Comment: The first 2 links are very useful, with the second one, django-socialsharing, being a really complete django social share app (you can share almost to anywhere), although based on the external services provided by [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com). The last link, instead, provides a useful list of social-related django apps available to the public, but the listed apps have nothing related to sharing: they provide social networks integrations in other ways: for example external authentication with social networks accounts or  features like "invite your friends". Anyway thanks from me too!

Comment: [django-addthis](https://github.com/raymondwanyoike/django-addthis) is a cleaned-up implementation of `django-socialsharing` and installed easily via pip: ```pip install django-addthis``` - Give it a try!

Comment: Here another app: [`django-social-widgets`](https://github.com/creafz/django-social-widgets), although currently `django-social-share` seems to be the best maintained one.

Comment: how i can share the blog different page on social site

Answer (score 4):

I found somethings. For Google, Linkedin, Facebook:

```
 <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://your-domain{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}"></a>
 <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://your-domain{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}&title=<your title>&summary=<your desc>&source=http://your-domain"></a>
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://your-domain{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}"></a>
```

Also, this [plugin (django-social-share)](https://pypi.org/project/django-social-share/) is very nice.
You can install it by:

```
pip install django-social-share
```

For using this plugin see the [Doc's page](https://pypi.org/project/django-social-share/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the following links working for whatsap,LinkedIn, Facebook, Twitter.

```html
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}" style="margin-right: 10px;">
<img data-src="#" class=" lazyloaded" loading="lazy" alt="Whatsapp" width="35" height="35" src="#">
</a>

<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}" style="margin-right: 10px;">
<img data-src="#" class=" lazyloaded" loading="lazy" alt="linkedin" width="35" height="35" src="#">                                   
</a>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}" style="margin-right: 10px;">
<img data-src="#" class=" lazyloaded" loading="lazy" alt="facebook" width="35" height="35" src="#">                                  
</a>

<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">
<img data-src="#" class=" lazyloaded" loading="lazy" alt="twitter" width="35" height="35" src="#">                                    
</a>
```

if you want to get the abosulte url you can use {{ request.build_ablsolute_uri }} or you can put your own url in that field.Also, please note that for linkedIn this may not work in localhost but worked for me once I deployed.