# How to add social share links to DetailView?

Tags: python, django

How do I add social sharing feature to my website build in Django. I saw a similar question in SO but that didn't help (below I explained why?), it was asked 6 years ago and I thought probably there must be better ways of doing it after these years.

I tried using [addthis](https://www.addthis.com/) ,it is elegant and easy to use, but this is the problem when I share a post in Facebook.

[image]

And also it didn't keep counts number of sharing a post.

I also tried other [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479779/social-media-link-share-in-post-django) either I didn't understand or it didn't work fine.
Please help me do this. Thank you very much.

edit: 
I am getting this error. after adding `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}&t={{ object.title }}">Share on Facebook</a>`

[image]

Comment: use this link for share `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ url }}&t={{ title }}`

Comment: how do I add `url` ? and please write other similar links for linkedln, google+, twitter as well.

Comment: put it in your templates and fill the url and title with your data. there is no google+ now. twitter `https://twitter.com/share?text={{ text }}&url={{ url }}&hashtags={{ hashtags }}`. linkedin `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn`

Comment: I can pass user using {{ user.username }}, I can add `title` as {{ object.title }} in template, how do I add that dynamic `url` in there?

Comment: for url you can use this `{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}`

Comment: thank you please write other links for linkedln, google+, twitter as well. it would be a great help

Comment: example => `https://twitter.com/share?text={{ user.username }}&url={{ request.get_full_path|urlencode}}`

Comment: can you please see above error, I edited the question and added the error.

Comment: try this. replace example.com with your domain.`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://example.com{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}&t={{ object.title }}">Share on Facebook</a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194014/discussion-between-noor-and-katoozi).

Answer (score 1):

use this for Facebook:

`{% with base_url="http://example.com" %} 
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ base_url|urlencode }}{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}&t={{ object.title }}">Share on Facebook</a> 
{% endwith %}`

for Twitter:

`{% with base_url="http://example.com" %} 
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?text={{ user.username }}&url={{ base_url|urlencode }}{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode}}">Share on Twitter</a> 
{% endwith %}`

for Linkedin: use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208363/sharing-a-url-with-a-query-string-on-twitter)