# Packages to share contents on social media with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

My app uses a Django backend and vuejs frontend, with API's served with Django Rest Framework. Now at the front end, I need to add social media links to share my contents on social media, notably Facebook, Instagram and Twitter. I have tried googling around for a resource but can't seems to find any, except django-rest-auth and allauth packages which work for authentication, not sharing. I will appreciate if anyone can direct or guide me to packages I can use for this purpose?

Comment: did you checked django-socialsharing https://github.com/lettertwo/django-socialsharing

Comment: also take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479779/social-media-link-in-django

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed. I saw the package but looks like it works for Django apps..In my case, I use Django rest framework, Django as backend and vuejs frontend.